# Переопределит блок с условиям

Tags: django, jinja2

```
{% extends "tablo/layout/app_layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block creeping_line %}
  <marquee> {{ creeping_line|safe }} </marquee>
{% endblock %}

{% block company_logo %}
  <img src = "/media/{{ company_logo }}" width = "40%">
{% endblock %}

{% block company_name %}
  <span> {{ company_name }} </span>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
  <span> {{ title }} </span>
{% endblock %}




{% if view == 0 %}
  {% block view %}

  {% endblock %}
{% if view == 1 %}
```

Вот посмотрите последное я с условиям переопределяю блок view. Если переменный view == 0 то нужно переопределит блок view

Comment: Можно пожалуйста больше информации

Comment: Я хочу переопределит блок по условиям

Comment: Пожалуйста покажите код

Comment: а переменную `view` передаете в шаблон?

Comment: Да переменную view передается из view.py на template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
{% block block_view %}
    {% if view == 0 %}
         {# Блок станет пустым #}
    {% elif view == 1 %}
        Замена
    {% else %}
        Добавление к имеющемуся контенту {{ block.super }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Значит block if не возможно принимать вне {% block block_name  endblock%}

Comment: Спасибо вам это очень правильное ответ  {{ block.super }}

Answer (score 0):

```
{% extends "tablo/layout/app_layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block creeping_line %}
  <marquee> {{ creeping_line|safe }} </marquee>
{% endblock %}

{% block company_logo %}
  <img src = "/media/{{ company_logo }}" width = "40%">
{% endblock %}

{% block company_name %}
  <span> {{ company_name }} </span>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
  <span> {{ title }} </span>
{% endblock %}


{% block client %}
  {{ client }}
{% endblock %}

{% block window %}
  {{ window }}
{% endblock %}

{% block rate %}
  {% if rate == 1 %}
    {{block.super}}
  {% else %}

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка править. И код надо вставлять не картинкой

Comment: Спасибо за советом